# PHP - Create user-defined function that calls str_replace, then calls ucfirst with the resulting string from str_replace

Tags: php, user-defined-functions, str-replace

I've only recently started learning PHP and had an idea that I've been trying to figure out how, or if, it's even possible.
The lesson I'm working on introduced str_replace and ucfirst, among other basic inbuilt functions.
After becoming familiar with basic code to use those functions, I started trying to figure out if I could create a function that does both.

The desired result is when I run fusion, it takes my arguments and passes them to str_replace.
The resulting string from str_replace is created as a variable called $vegeta.

```
    <?php 
             
            $var1 = "Beginner PHP is starting to";
            $var2 = ":";
            $var3 = "make sense";
            $var4 = "prepare";
            $var5 = "excite ";
            $var6 = " me!";
            $var7 = $var1;
            $var7 .= $var2;
            $var8 = $var5;
            $var8 .=$var6;  
            
                          
        
            function fusion($find, $replace, $string)
                {
                    $vegeta = str_replace();
                    $goku = ucfirst($vegeta);
                    echo $goku;
                }
        ?>
        
        <?php echo $var7; ?> <br />
        <?php echo $var3; ?> <br />
        <?php echo $var4; ?> <br />
        <?php echo $var8; ?> <br /><br /><br />
        
        <?php echo $var7; ?> <br />
        <?php fusion("make sense", "force me", $var3); ?> <br />
        <?php fusion("excite me", "to think outside the box", $var8); ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal with the `fusion()` function? Just executing `str_replace()` does not do anything, you need to give it arguments to tell it what to do. Here is some documentation on what `str_replace()` does in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
**Edit**: Oops, my bad. I misread your post. It looks like you're just trying to pass the variables from your `fusion()` function onto the `str_replace()` function. I'll post an answer to explain below

Comment: You should have gotten an error `str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 0 given`. If not then search for "PHP error reporting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just pass on the arguments you have in your `fusion()` function, to the `str_replace()` function inside. That function requires 3 arguments, just like your own function has. Yours are called `$find, $replace, $string` and the PHP function expects `$search, $replace, $subject`. It seems like these arguments mean the same thing, meaning you can just directly pass them on like this:

```php
function fusion($find, $replace, $string)
{
    $vegeta = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
    $goku = ucfirst($vegeta);
    echo $goku;
}
```

That will pass on the arguments to `str_replace()` and then execute the `ucfirst()` on the result.